# Xcode table view and segue, variable not delivered

Tags: uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, segue

I'm trying to make my app display a different webpage for every row of a tableview, but running it, when I tap a row it display a white page!
This is the code of the table view:

```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowPDF"]) {

    Tab2_ItemViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

    NSInteger selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];

    NSString *stringaProva = [dataArrayLink objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];

    vc.selectedItem = stringaProva;

    }
    }

    @end
```

And this is the code for the subview:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
  {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:selectedItem];
    NSURLRequest *httpRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:httpRequest];

   }
```

If I write a url manually instead of `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:selectedItem];` it works with no problem, so I'm guessing the problem is that the segue doesn't deliver the right variable... Can someone help?

Comment: what u get if u do NSLog(@"%@", selectedItem ); in viewDidLoad?

Comment: i get the correct web address...

Answer (score 0):

Check `stringaProva` has `value` before `passing` to `selectedItem`

Use like this:

```
if(self.selectedItem) 
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.selectedItem];
else
  NSLog(@"selectedItem has no value");
```